# How can I log out of Facebook Messenger?

Tags: 8.1, apps, store, facebook, messenger

I have a Lumia 430 Dual-SIM with Windows Phone 8.1. After some research, I came across [this site](https://www.androidpit.com/how-to-log-out-of-facebook-messenger), but it only give details on how to log out using Android. I then thought of uninstalling Facebook Messenger and installing it again with the idea given on the site I mentioned, but the Store keeps showing me a "805a8011" error message which I was told to hard reset my phone to fix that, but I can't. I just have too many files to backup with little amount of internet bandwidth, meaning I'm currently using 2g network and my Spectranet is downloading at 145 kb/s.

In a nutshell, I thought of different alternatives that aren't actually in my favor, so the answer I'm expecting is one without resetting my phone but any other apart from that is welcomed.

Comment: I no longer have any 8.1 devices to hand, but I seem to remember that Facebook showed up as an account under Settings > Accounts, you should be able to remove it there

Comment: I've checked Settings in the facebook messenger but there is no sign of Accounts.